# How to import and play all audio files from a directory in React?

Tags: reactjs, file, import, html5-audio

I am trying to play each audio file located inside a directory using React. I can play one file as follows but I do not want to import each file since there 70 files in the folder:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import audio1 from '../../Storage/Audio/1.wav';

const Mp3player = () =>  {
  const audioEl = new Audio(audio1);

  const handlePlay = () =>{
    audioEl.play();
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    audioEl.load();
  }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Player </h1>
        <button onClick={handlePlay}> Play </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
export default Mp3player;
```

I tried this:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

const r = require.context('../../Storage/Audio', false, /\.(wav)$/);

let audios  = [];
r.keys().forEach((item) => {audios.push('file:../../Storage/Audio/' + String(item).substring(2))});
console.log(audios)

const Mp3player = () =>  {
  const audioEl = new Audio(audios[0]);
  console.log(audios[0]);

  const handlePlay = () =>{
    audioEl.play();
    console.log("playing");

  }
    useEffect(() => {
    audioEl.load();
  }, []);

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Player </h1>
        <button onClick={handlePlay}> Play </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
export default Mp3player;
```

But no success playing the file.

How can I import and play all the audio files and get them inside an array or object?

EDIT: My `.wav` files are named `1.wav` to `70.wav`, if that helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the way I managed to solve it:

1. I have my videos in the `public` folder. For the purpose of this example, they are named: `video1.mp4` and `video2.mp4`.
2. I used `react-player` library.

This is the resulting code:

```
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

function App() {
  const videoNames = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    videoNames.push(`video${i}.mp4`);
  }

  const Videos = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        {videoNames.map((videoName) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>{videoName}</h1>
              <ReactPlayer url={videoName} controls={true} />;
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return <Videos />;
}

export default App;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had te same problem and at the end i installed a package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player

Is open source,  Either to check the code or use it in your project... this could help you

Comment: could you please elaborate more on your answer so I can accept it? for example, give an example code importing all files from folder. Thanks.