# Sound effects from public folder failed to load in deployment

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, http-status-code-404, vite

As the title suggests, I deployed my site but it fails to load the sound effects.

Repo:https://github.com/SyntaxWarrior30/Documentation-Wizard/tree/2bea2b4781933f29f773b4fec52a806c31bcec70

Active Site: https://syntaxwarrior30.github.io/Documentation-Wizard/

This is how I try to load the sound effects from the public folder, in `src/DocsGen.jsx`:

```
DocsGen.jsx
Line 30 | const successAudio = new Audio('/public/Success.wav');
Line 31 | const errorAudio = new Audio('/public/Error.wav');
```

I have also tried:

```
DocsGen.jsx
Line 30 | const successAudio = new Audio('/Success.wav');
Line 31 | const errorAudio = new Audio('/Error.wav');
```

Both resulted in `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the  404 loading error. Reference code below:

```
  const successAudio = new Audio('./Success.wav');
  const errorAudio = new Audio('./Error.wav');
```

Answer (score 0):

Public folder is a special folder in react which is outside of the scope of react bundle.

To use assets inside public folder you just directly reference them.

> const successAudio = new Audio('/Success.wav');

> const errorAudio = new Audio('/Error.wav');

Here is a relevant thread: [How to import and play all audio files from a directory in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251541/how-to-import-and-play-all-audio-files-from-a-directory-in-react)

Comment: I tried, still results in 404.